# Vue.js Blank Page Issue When Concatenating Two Notification Arrays Using Spread Operator

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm facing an issue while using spread operator within a reactive attribute in Vue.js. I'm creating a notifications dropdown that consists of two types of notifications: friend requests and group invitations. I retrieve these notifications through two separate backend requests. In the first request, I use map to add a type atribute, and simply assign the fetched notifications to a notifications array. In the second request, I intend to concatenate the notifications from both types using the spread operator. However, upon doing this, the page goes blank without showing any errors.

```
<div id="scrollable" class="vld-parent p-2" ref="notificatons_list">
        <div
          class="notification-item"
          v-for="(notification, index) in notifications"
          :key="'notification_' + index"
        >
          <div
            v-if="notification.type === 'group'"
         ...
```

```
data() {
    return {
      ...
      notifications: []
    };
  },
```

```
async mounted() {
    await this.handleLoadGroupRequests();
    await this.handleLoadFriendshipRequests();
  },
```

```
async handleLoadGroupRequests() {
      ...
      try {
        const { data } = await api.get(`/${this.endpoint}/groups/requests`);
        this.notifications = data.map(notification => ({
          ...notification,
          type: "group"
        }));
      ...
    },
```

```
async handleLoadFriendshipRequests() {
      try {
        const { data } = await api.get(
          `/${this.endpoint}/friendships/requests`
        );
        const newNotifications = data.map(item => ({
          ...item,
          type: "friendship"
        }));
        this.notifications = [...this.notifications, ...newNotifications]; // here the problem happens
      }...
    },
```

I attempted an alternative approach by using a for loop to manually push notifications into the array. While this method works, Vue doesn't seem to detect the changes made. If I log the array, I can see all the notifications, but during rendering, Vue displays the array in its previous state from the second request.

Could you please help me identify the problem and how to solve it?

Comment: did you try pushing like `this.notifications.push(...newNotifications)` - it *should* work (though, your for loop method should have too)

Comment: if pushing like `this.notifications.push(...newNotifications)` the problem keeps happening. I changed some blocks of the code so now the for loop method is working.  However can't understand why the spread or push methods doesn't work.

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when "it doesn't work"?

Comment: @GilsonGarcia Spread Operator should not contain any issue here. Example : https://jsfiddle.net/07jtqxp3/